# Ballerina: retrieve record from table structure by passing parameter

Tags: ballerina

I want to retrieve a record from table data structure by passing a variable to the where clause. But it works only when value is hard coded and not when given as a parameter.

```
public function getEmployeeEmail(string GITHUB_ID_VALUE) returns string{
    string WSO2_EMAIL;

    table<Employee> employeeTableCopyWithFilter = from tableEmployee where GITHUB_ID == GITHUB_ID_VALUE select *;

    json jsonTable = check <json>employeeTableCopyWithFilter;
    return jsonTable[0].WSO2_EMAIL.toString();
}
```

It throws an error like this.

```
error: ballerina/runtime:CallFailedException, message: call failed
    at org/wso2/org:0.0.1:GitHubStarsDetector.executeOperation(service.bal:40)
caused by ballerina/runtime:CallFailedException, message: call failed
    at org/wso2/org:0.0.1:getMissingIds(github_repository_scanner.bal:54)
caused by error, message: error in executing statement : CREATE TABLE TABLE_EMPLOYEE_3 AS select *  from (select * from TABLE_EMPLOYEE_1 where GITHUB_ID = id) error:Column "ID" not found; SQL statement:
CREATE FORCE VIEW PUBLIC._0 AS
SELECT
    TABLE_EMPLOYEE_1.USER_ID,
    TABLE_EMPLOYEE_1.NAME,
    TABLE_EMPLOYEE_1.GITHUB_ID,
    TABLE_EMPLOYEE_1.WSO2_EMAIL
FROM PUBLIC.TABLE_EMPLOYEE_1
WHERE GITHUB_ID = ID [42122-197]
    at org/wso2/org:0.0.1:getEmployeeEmail(database_handler.bal:102)
```

However it works fine when I hard code a value to `GITHUB_ID_VALUE` parameter.

```
public function getEmployeeEmail(string GITHUB_ID_VALUE) returns string{
        string WSO2_EMAIL;

        table<Employee> employeeTableCopyWithFilter = from tableEmployee where GITHUB_ID == "MadhukaHarith92" select *;

        json jsonTable = check <json>employeeTableCopyWithFilter;
        return jsonTable[0].WSO2_EMAIL.toString();
    }
```

Does anyone know how to pass a variable and retrieve record from table structure?

Comment: This looks like a limitation with the in-memory table. The reason is because, currently all the in-memory table queries are build at compile time and it does not take any expression evaluation into consideration which happens at runtime. Please open up a github issue to get this fixed.

Comment: Issue created https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/11023